# Is there anything to replace public and Serialize Field?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I like to use SerializeField to display variables in the Inspector window in Unity C#.
But I think the code line is too long and complicated to put SerializeField before each variable.
Is there any other concise alternative to SerializeField?
I hope my question doesn't go against the rules. Please answer me. Thanks! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAtor.png)

Comment: Nope ... among others these are the main [serialization rules of Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html#SerializationRules) A field is either `public` or attributed `[SerializeField]`

Comment: Your code lines are definitely not too long or complicated! You can skip the redundant `= null` though

Comment: Thank you for your answer guys. 
I thought there might be a grammar that I didn't know, but I guess there wasn't